# Is the Google Earth VR sdk out for development yet? Can't seem to find it?

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I've been trying to search SDK for Google Earth VR for development but can't find anything. Is it out yet? Doesn't show anything here: https://vr.google.com/earth/
If not, are there any other similar maps which I can use for development?
I'm trying to make a project which is basically a Trivia using Google Earth Maps in VR.

Comment: Same need. Have you found something ?

Comment: No. Not yet. I guess there is nothing out yet..